why $|f_n| \to |f|$ if $f_n \to f$?
Here is what I have as givens: $f_n , f \in L^1$ and $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $\int |f_n|
 \to \int |f|.$
My professor defined $h_n = |f_n| + |f| - |f_n - f|$ and then she concluded that $h_n \to 2|f|$ a.e.
I am wondering why this is correct? Could someone explain this to me please?

Your title is, of course, false. Don’t you mean $|f_n|\to |f|$ a.e.?

@TedShifrin yes I mean that sorry

You should be more explicit about which convergence mode you mean for $|f_n|$.

I mean the ordinary pointwise convergence .... No convergence in measure or anything@CameronWilliams

$||a|-|b||\le |a-b|$

Just use triangle inequality:
$\left|\left|f_n(x)\right|-\left|f(x)\right|\right|\leq\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|$.

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence converging to $a$. Then $|a_n - a| \to 0$ by definition. Also, $|a_n| \to |a|$ because the absolute value function is continuous.
Thus, if $f_n \to f$ a.e., then for a.e. $x$, we have $f_n(x) \to f(x)$, which implies $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$ and $|f_n(x)| \to |f(x)|$.
